# Python Decorators with function arguments

Tags: python, numpy, decorator, argument-passing

I have a simple function, defined as follows:

```
def simple_function(x):
    """ x is an input numpy array"""
    return x + 0.1
```

I want to modify this function by applying some boundary conditions to it. These boundary conditions are themselves functions of x:

```
def upper_bound(x):
    return x**2

def lower_bound(x):
    return np.zeros(len(x))
```

In particular, if the `simple_function(x)` exceeds the value of `upper_bound(x)`, or falls below `lower_bound(x)`, I want the decorated version of `simple_function(x)` to return the value `upper_bound(x)`, and likewise for lower_bound. How can I accomplish this behavior using the @decorator syntax in python?

Answer (score 2):

If your arguments, bounds and results are all numpy arrays, you can do a couple of array assignments to clamp each element between the corresponding values returned by your `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` functions. The core part is:

```
r = f(x)
l = lower_bound(x)
u = upper_bound(x)

i = r < l
j = r > u

r[i] = l
r[j] = u
```

`i` and `j` will be Boolean arrays that say which indexes need to be clamped to the lower and upper bounds, respectively. To make this code work as a decorator, you just need to put it inside a pair of nested functions, like so:

```
def clamp(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(x):
        r = f(x)
        l = lower_bound(x)
        u = upper_bound(x)

        i = r < l
        j = r > u

        r[i] = l
        r[j] = u

        return r

    return wrapper
```

`functools.wraps` makes it so the wrapper function copies the name, annotations and docstring of the decorated function.

The code above assumes that you're always using the same `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` functions. If you need those to be customizable for different functions you're decorating, you can add an extra layer of nesting and define a "decorator factory" like in Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer:

```
def clamp(lower_bound, upper_bound):   # this is the decorator factory function
    def decotator(f):                  # this is the decorator function
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(x):                # this is the wrapper function
            ... # same code here as above
            return r

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Comment: Bickknght, that is some beautiful code. My implementation this works marvelously, thanks!

Comment: My only, super minor adjustment is simply in making your boolean conditions work better with numpy arrays: r = np.where(r < l, l, r). But this decorator factory design is really fantastic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Other than modifying `__doc__` et alia, here you are:

```
def constrain(lower, upper):
  def outer(f):
    def inner(x):
      r = f(x)
      u = upper(x)
      if r > u:
        return u
      l = lower(x)
      if r < l:
        return l
      return r
    return inner
  return outer
```

...

```
@constrain(lower_bound, upper_bound)
def simple_function(x):
   ...
```

Differing types and the lower bound being higher than the upper bound are not handled.

Comment: Great answer! This works great and is an excellent syntax template for single variable arguments, but it does not work for numpy arrays. Know how to jigger the syntax for that purpose?

Comment: A NumPy array is a single argument. Are you seeing any *specific* issues?

Comment: I suspect the issue isn't with the arguments, but the return values. You can't compare numpy arrays the same way you compare scalars (you either need to use `all`, or to do an element-wise replacement of the out-of-bounds values, rather than just returning `l` or `u`).